# PHP: get string between the last two designated characters

Tags: php, string, explode

I have some pictures which file names look like this:

- my-picture_001.79-420x230.jpg
- mypicture-002-210x370.png
- etc...

Whatever the file name, it will always end with:" -NumberxNumber.Extension "

Here it would be :
"-420x230.jpg " and "-210x370.png"

What I would like is to be able to always retrieve the two last numbers.

I tried to use the "explode" function but there may be so many "-" and "." and "x" in the filename that it doesn't help.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode`, the amount of '-'s and 'x's shouldn't matter since you always need a specific one.

```
$string = 'my-picture_001.79-420x230.jpg';

$last_half = end(explode('-', $string));     // '420x230.jpg'
$last_sec = reset(explode('.',$last_half));  // '420x230'
$values = explode('x', $last_sec);

echo $values[0] // '420'
echo $values[1] // '230'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strrchr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) to find the last occurrence of a "-" and return the rest of the string from that point till the end. From there you should be able to easily extract what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should you regular expression to extract those 2 numbers.

```
<?php
$reg = '/(\d*)x(\d*).\D*/i';
$string = 'my-picture_001.79-420x230.jpg';

preg_match($reg, $string, $matches);

//print the result
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

/D stands for non digit characters 
/d stands for digit characters
/D* means zero or more non digit characters
and the characters we want to extract will be located inside ()...

I usually use this site to play with regex:
http://rubular.com/ 
and this is a tutorial about regular expression in php 
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will use the explode solution but this is still good/